# Service is created again after onTaskRemoved

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I made a remote service, this service is started by my activity the first time that boot, after that, the activity always look if the service is started to avoid start it again.

The service run some methods in the onCreate function. This service is running always and started on boot time also.

The problem (is not a big problem but I want to know why) is that once the service is created if I stop my activity the onTaskRemoved is called, this is correct, but after few seconds the oncreate method is called again and the service starts again.

Any idea why? And how can I control this?

```
<service
        android:name=".Service"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:process=":update_process" >
</service>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
if (!isRunning()) {
    Intent service = new Intent(this, UpdateService.class);
    startService(service);
} else {
    //Just to debug, comment it later
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service was running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**When the service is started if it was not running**

Comment: I'm not clear with your question. But don't worry about multiple instances of the service. Calling [`startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) from the second times doesn't start the service twice, if it is already running.

Comment: @LaiVung the multiple instance is not the problem, the problem is that the method oncreate is called after the activity had stop, so the methods inside the onCreate are called again, and I don't want.

Comment: Do you start something in the end of your activity (`onDestroy()` for example)?

Comment: nop, just onPause I do an Unbind if the service was bind

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problems is that you service is sticky per default, this means that it will be restarted when killed, until you explicitly ask for it to be stopped.

Override the `onStartCommand()` method in your service, and have it return `START_NOT_STICKY`. Then you service will not be restarted when killed.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: @Marcel: Now other people searching for an answer to this problem can also see the solution :)

Answer (score 7):

Although Bjarke's solution is valid, I would like to propose an alternate solution which covers cases where it might be necessary to perform any recovery in the Service.

Android is invoking `onStartCommand()` once again after restarting your service to inform you that the Service process crashed unexpectedly (because its task stack was removed), and is now being restarted.

If you look at the `intent` argument of `onCreate()`, it will be `null` (only for such restarts), which indicates that Android is re-creating your previously sticky service which crashed unexpectedly.

In some cases it would be wise to return `NON_STICKY` ONLY for such restarts, perform any needed cleanup/recovery and stop the service so that you exit gracefully.

When the service is started normally, you should still be returning `STICKY` otherwise your service would never be restarted to let you perform any recovery.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    // intent is null only when the Service crashed previously
    if (intent == null) {
        cleanupAndStopServiceRightAway();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void cleanupAndStopServiceRightAway() {
        // Add your code here to cleanup the service

        // Add your code to perform any recovery required
        // for recovering from your previous crash

        // Request to stop the service right away at the end
        stopSelf();
}
```

Another option would be to request your service be stopped (using `stopSelf()`) as part of `onTaskRemoved()` so that Android does not even have to kill the service in the first place.

Comment: Can you save something to database in that?